# Good way to switch between 2 versions of the same dependency in package.json?

Tags: javascript, python, json, electron, yarnpkg

Turns out you can't have comments in JSON files, and it's a bit awkward to have people refer to some documentation telling them what line to copy/paste in and where in order to achieve this.

I think I can make a python script to copy/paste in one of two package.json files depending on what flags they pass in, but that feels overcomplicated.

I think I can include both dependencies (under different names) but that would create a requirement for both to be available, which is not good either.

Looking for ideas/thoughts on a good way to accomplish this. I have a release and dev version of the same dependency and I often need to swap between the two. Would like to improve the workflow beyond just having a notepad on the side with the two lines pasted in it...

Comment: You could just create two git branches with the difference package.json file. Git checkout branch-name-package1 package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yarn` and `npm` already do this job, why not use them?

#### Releases

[Tag](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-dist-tag) the dev versions when you release them

```
yarn publish --tag dev dep
npm publish --tag dev dep
```

Then reference the tag at install time `yarn install dep@dev`.

#### Local

For local dependencies, `npm` and `yarn` provide the "link" command.

In your dependency dir run `yarn link`
In you project dir run `yarn link dep`

You could document the commands as scripts so easy to run or view.

```
"scripts" : {
  "dep:local": "yarn link dep",
  "dep:dev": "yarn install dep@dev",
  "dep:latest": "yarn install dep@latest"
}
```

Comment: the dev versions aren't always released, I'm working off a local relative path sometimes too. This will work for some cases, thank you for that, but what about switching between like `"mypkg": "../../sources/mypkg"` and a published version?

Comment: `npm`/`yarn link` will do local